# draw line between two cordinates in ondraw() in android

Tags: android, canvas, line

I have two points , lets say (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Now i have to draw a line between these points using `OnDraw()` method.

I tried as

```
Paint mPaint = new Paint()     
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);    
path.moveTo(x1, y1);    
path.lineTo(x2, y2);

canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

But its not working

Regards,

Sudheer

Comment: How is it not working? What happens?

Comment: Please add some details on what doesn't work, and check that x1,x2,y1,y2 have sensible values (e.g. not outside the visible area). The code looks okay to me and should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
canvas.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, paint);
```